# Download file depending on mimetype in casperjs

Tags: phantomjs, mime-types, casperjs, slimerjs

In a web scraping exercise, I need to click on links, let them render the content if is html and download it otherwise. How do I accomplish this with casperjs or some other tools on top of phantom/slimerjs?

As I understand it, phantom/slimerjs lack the APIs to support download. casperjs has a download API but I am not able to see how to examine the mime type and let the html render while download other content.

Comment: @tripleee I have edited my question to include my research. My question is self-contained and, as far as I know, has a complex issue not addressed in the usual examples across the Web. I don't think it deserved a negative vote.

Comment: For the record, I'm not the downvoter. I have not looked into this in any detail, but would not allowing the browser to take its default action for the clicked links work for you?

Comment: @tripleee thanks. The above tools that I am using do not have a default action for non-Web content such as pdfs, application binaries, etc.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please add a constructive comment for your reasons to down vote, so that I can improve my question?

Comment: You have tagged both slimerjs and phantomjs - do you need a solution that works in both, or is just one or other good enough? (They differ slightly in the area you want to use them in.)

Comment: One is good enough. For lack of a solution, I switched to using Watir and at least I have a working tool. However, it will be good to know something that works on at least one of phantomjs and slimerjs.

Answer (score 2):

In both PhantomJS and SlimerJS you can register a listener to each received response:

```
page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
...
}
```

However, only in SlimerJS is response.body defined. By using this you can save the file. There is a full example in [this blog post](http://darrendev.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/saving-downloaded-files-in-slimerjs-and.html). (As that example shows, you must set `page.captureContent` to cover the files you want data for.)

There is no way to do this in PhantomJS 1.9.x (and I believe PhantomJS 2.x still has the same problem, but I have not personally confirmed this yet).

The other part of your question was about deciding what to save based on mime type. The [full list of available fields](http://docs.slimerjs.org/nightly/api/webpage.html#webpage-onresourcereceived) shows you can use `response.contentType`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer and the blog post link. I will test it once I get back to it.